# Totals in table visual is not shown in power BI

Tags: powerbi

I'm using powerbi desktop version and I've added a measure as a column in the table visual.
Enabled totals as well but unfortunately I'm not able to see the total value of that particular column to be displayed.
The same table contains several other measures for which the total appears but not for one particular column. This has data type decimal number.
Any suggestions?

TIA!!!

Comment: Check your measure (you can edit the query and show it - no one will help you without it);

Comment: Totals Filter = 
VAR _CurLoss = ROUND ( [Total Loss_1], 2 )
VAR _Loss1 =
IF (
NOT ISBLANK ( _CurLoss ),
ROUND (
CALCULATE (
 [Total Loss_1],
REMOVEFILTERS ( Table1),
REMOVEFILTERS ( table2)
),
2
)
)
RETURN
IF ( _CurLoss <> 0 && _Loss1= 0, _CurLoss )

Comment: Can anyone please help?
#powerbi #daxformula